# Can't use a mocked Interface class in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, mocking

I'm trying to mock a method in my Unit Test but I can't debug into the the method from the service.

I have a service with the method DoSomething1 that I want to test :

```
public MyService : IMyService
{
    private IAnotherService _anotherService;

    public MyService(IAnotherService anotherService)
    {
        _anotherService = anotherService;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething1(string param)
    {
        // Code...
        _anotherService.DoSomething2(string param1, string param2);
        // Code...
    }
}
```

This is my testing class :

```
[TestClass]
public class MyServiceTests : TestBase
{
    private Mock<IAnotherService> _mockAnotherService;
    
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockAnotherService = new Mock<IAnotherService>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test_MyService_DoSomething()
    {
        var myService = new MyService(_mockAnotherService.Object);

        var result = myService.DoSomething1(param1);

        // Some Asserts...
    }
}
```

If I now debug it I can get into MyService but I can't debug into

```
_anotherService.DoSomething2(string param1, string param2);
```

And it will fail my tests.

Using this works but seems to be bad practice :

```
var myService = Container.GetInstance<MyService>();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: your `_anotherService` is mocked. Why do you need to debug into the mocked method?

Comment: Because it is not doing what it should do.

Comment: You have not Setup your mock. [Look at the quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: The method is mocked. What do you expect it to do? It's not the original method anymore

Comment: If I do var service = Container.GetInstance<MyService>(); my tests passes.

Comment: If you do that, you're using the real `IAnotherService` which sounds like an integration test, not unit test.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a mock is to be a stand-in for the real thing. In testing scenarios it is often undesirable to have the whole object graph wired up, because it is often hard to set up, parts of it might interact with resources that are not available/slow/unreliable, or it might make it much harder, if not impossible to invoke certain edge cases or error scenarios.

In a comment you state that using `Container.GetInstance<MyService>()` instead of setting it up with a mock is passing your tests. This means you are using the real implementation of `IAnotherService`. If this is not posing any problems then do that. If you are unable to invoke certain test cases with "the real thing" or it turns out that your tests become brittle or slow, then mock it.

If you use a mock of `IAnotherService` then the instance of it is not going to do anything by itself. You can tell the mock to return something, but that is pretty much it. e.g.

```
_mockAnotherService.Setup(m => m.DoSomething2("a", "b")).Returns(42);
```

The mock wont be able to simulate any side effects (i.e. writing to a DB or file). You have to simulate that directly in your test. Debugging into the mocked version of `DoSomething2()`, if it were possible for you, would only show you how the Moq is implementing its mocks. Assume that they are doing the right thing and that it makes no sense to debug. It is not the real `DoSomething2()`.

Comment: Hmm ok well the thing is that _anotherService.DoSomething2(string param1, string param2); is writing stuff to the db.